# How to add a dropdown list using HTML and populate it with information from an SQL DB?

Tags: html, sql-server-2005

I have created a form, but but would like the first field to be a dropdown box. I need this dropdown box to be populated with information from an SQL database. I am quite new to web developing but have a basic level of knowledge. The database is setup and the information is available to populate the dropdown. The code I have for the form is below:

```
<form name="Enter New Model" method="Post" action="savePerson.asp">

<table>
<tr><td><h3>Serial No: </td></h3>
<td><input type="text" name="SerialNo" size="50"></td></tr>
<tr><td><h3>Make/Model: </td></h3>
<td><input type="text" name="[Make/Model]" size="50"></td></tr>
<tr><td><h3>Next Upgrade: </td></h3>
<td><input type="text" name="NextUpgrade" size="50"></td></tr>
<tr><td><h3>Stock: </td></h3>
<td><input type="text" name="Stock" size="50"></td></tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

The serial no field needs to be a dropdown.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a server side code to do this. There are many available, such as ASP.net or PHP, Node, etc etc...

Comment: So I would need to code the dropdown in a server side code or do you mean the population of the dropdown needs to be coded in server side code?

Comment: Just within dotnet there are many, ways to bind a DropDownList to a database query. Using Databinding is probably preferred, but you could roll you own methods to. Any dotnet tutorial should probably cover databinding, a very good one is here http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_databinding.asp but notice that this is about half way through the WebForms tutorial - I strongly recommend that you start at the introduction to webforms. There are many other great online free dotnet tutorials.